# Django template if statement not updating

Tags: django, templates

I have an if statement in a django template that checks if the views.count variable is bigger than 0 to display a button. Once my views.count increases my if statement doesn't update and I do not understand why, since I am updating the variable using javascript. I other section of my template I'm iterating the views and it updates correctly.

```
        {% if views.count > 0 %}
        <a class="btn preview__tour">{% trans 'Preview tour' %}</a>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: How can you update a Django template variable using Javascript?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django templates render the code only once on page load. It does not render again unless you refresh the page. So updating the variable using javascript won't trigger the template to render again, unless it triggers a page reload.